# Executable on solaris in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, solaris

I have an executable which run on Solaris. I am trying to run the same in Ubuntu. When I run with KSH or SH it is throwing error. Can you please let me know how to run an executable compatible in Solaris on Ubuntu. The problem I am facing is I have only the executable and does not have the source code to recompile the code on  Linux. Is there a way to run the executable compiled for Solaris run on Ubuntu

I get this exception when I run using KSH

```
cannot execute [Exec format error]
```

Sh throws this error

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What executable, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

When you compile a program on linux a lot of programs use third party libraries. If those libraries are not installed or if there is a different version on the other machine the executable will not run. You are likely missing *dependencies* as they are called. More on that [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/420518/339961).
A program may use different system calls and libraries which may not be available on different derivatives.
On top of that an executable is compiled for a specific processor. If you use a different instruction set, say 32bit instead of 64bit or an ARM or AMD instead of an Intel it will/may also not run. More on this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420513/will-a-linux-executable-compiled-on-one-flavor-of-linux-run-on-a-different-one).
If you want to compile for multiple distributions using the same architecture you can use the linux standard base. More on that [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/420534/339961).

In short: you have to recompile/fetch the correct version for your system instead of just copying the executable.